# How to have the HTMLParser continue parsing after a parse error?

Tags: python, html, parsing, html-parsing

I am creating a web crawler and I use HTMLParser module to parse the links out of an HTML document. If the parser comes across bad markup it raises a parse error and terminates the application. Since the crawler traverses the whole web this error gets raised quite often.

On the python.org bug section, someone already raised this issue. You can look at that [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue755660). The problem with this is that I don't really know how to use the "patch" that is provided and I don't understand the comments.

I want override the default behavior the HTMLParser module to allow it to continue parsing after a parse error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) instead of HTMLParser. BeautifulSoup is much more robust.

> Beautiful Soup won't choke if you give it bad markup. It yields a parse tree that makes approximately as much sense as your original document. This is usually good enough to collect the data you need and run away.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use HTMLParser myself, but can you not just place your statement in a try/except block?

```
try:
  myval = HTMLParser.flimsyFunction()
except HTMLParser.ParseError:
  myval = None
```

Comment: The problem with that is that it will not continue parsing the same HTML document. It will just move on to the next page. I want it to try to parse as much of the document as possible.

Answer (score 0):

There are certain blogs and pages who do not want their pages to be scanned and parsed via bots and parser programs. They want many parsers to give error situations.

Many a times its written in the code of the webpage as

```
document.write('<sci'+<pt'...)
```

in this way via javascript the users try to insert code but when this whole feed is set to be parsed the parser gives an error saying that a "bad tag was encountered" and it stops.

The best way to solve this problem is before parsing just remove all the javascript code in case you just need the content, and you'll be working just fine :)

Comment: That's just bady written pages, there's no telling what that could do to any browser, let alone poor screen readers and other accessible browsers.